# Can I scale devices on Google Cloud ML for predictions?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Does Google Cloud ML predictions run on multiple devices, or a single device?

I find my Google ML preductions running at ~7sec but when running my model locally with a Flask server on a 4-core machine it takes ~1.8-2.1 sec.

Is there a way to increase the number of devices/resources I am using on Google Cloud ML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use more resources to serve your predictions. However the feature is still at alpha stage and it will only be available to a selected list of accounts who opted in as "Trusted Testers". Please contact cloudml-feedback@google.com if you need help to setup prediction service using multicores.